Is there any way to check transaction status of spl transfer using signature hash
Please help me find the solution, like we did on solscan using signature hash to find the transaction status of spl token.

You can use the getSignatureStatuses RPC method to check the status of transaction. You can ping it and if it doesnt return anything by the time the blockhash expires your transaction probably didnt land. But if it does return a value it will show you if any instruction errors occurred or if it was successful. You can also use the getTransaction method to get more information like the balance changes, instruction logs, fee paid, etc for a transaction.

i have used @solana/web3.js getSignatureStatuses and getTransaction but getSignatureStatuses giving me null even the transaction is failed or success and this getTransaction giving me some errors.

When you get the transaction hash do you check it on an explorer? And if it shows it is successful and then try running the rpc methods does it still return null? Also when sending a transaction do you wait for it to be confirmed before you start checking the signature statuses? Can you maybe provide your the error messages/the code youre using, it will help to diagnose your issue

it might issue with cluster, would you recommend me what cluster to use for consistent results

I personally use Helius, their free RPC is pretty reliable. But also if you don't have any priority fees added to your transaction it has a good chance of not landing.
